# Find all real values of x and y such that $\left(x+yi\right)^3$ is real and greater than $8$, represent these values in the xy-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My solution

$\left(x+yi\right)^3>8$

$\left(x^3-3xy^2-8\right)+\left(3x^2y-y^3\right)i>0$

and now I'm stuck with these equations

$\left(x^3-3xy^2-8\right)>0,\left(3x^2y-y^3\right)>0$

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field. So comparison between numbers in this set is meaningless. Check with your teacher before posting.

Comment: Hint: assuming the problem is correctly stating, you want the cube roots in $\Bbb C$ of positive reals greater than $8$.

Comment: This is from an engineering entrance exam

Comment: I also edited the question

Comment: You want $3 x^2 y - y^3 = 0$, not $>$.  That is, the imaginary part of $(x+yi)^3$ must be $0$ to make $(x+yi)^3$ real.  Hint: polar coordinates.

Comment: @WangYeFei in the title the OP says $(x+iy)$ real and greater than $8$. You’re right when you say that $\mathbb C$ is not an ordered field but once you restrict on $\mathbb R$ the order makes sense as a notion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the cube is real then

$$3x^2y-y^3 =y(3x^2-y^2)=0$$

(and not $3x^2y-y^3>0$) then we have three cases

- $y=0 \land x\neq 0 \implies x^3-8>0 \implies \begin{cases}x>2\\y=0 \end{cases}$
- $y\neq 0 \land 3x^2=y^2\neq 0 \implies x^3-9x^3-8>0 \implies \begin{cases}x<-1\\y=\pm \sqrt 3 x \end{cases}$
- $y=0 \land x= 0 \implies -8>0$

---

As an alternative by polar coordinates

$$z=re^{i\theta} \implies z^3=r^3e^{i3\theta}$$

that is

$$r^3\cos (3\theta)>8 \land \sin (3\theta)=0$$

therefore we have

- $3\theta = 2k\pi \implies \theta = \frac 2 3 k\pi$, with $k=0,1,2$
- $r>2$

which indicates that solutions are three oriented lines out of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer is correct or not but this is my idea:

$(x+yi)^3= r^3(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)^3,$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi \in [-\pi,\pi)$.

By de Moivre's formula, we have

$(x+yi)^3= r^3(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)^3 = r^3(\cos(3\phi)+i\sin(3\phi)).$

Since this is real, then $\sin(3\phi)=0 \Leftrightarrow \phi = \dfrac{k\pi}{3}$, where $k\in \lbrace -1, 0, 1\rbrace$.

Then  $(x+yi)^3= r^3 = \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right)^3$.

So $ \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right)^3 >8 \Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2 > 4$. Then in the $xy$-plane, this is the domain outside a circle with $(0,0)$ as a center and radius $2$.

Comment: Your solution is almost fine, but you need to specify better the conditions on $\phi$.

Comment: Ah yes, i see, didn't notice it. Thank you so much

Comment: You need to fix $\sin(3\phi)=0 \Leftrightarrow \phi = 0, \frac 2 3 \pi, \frac 4 3 \pi$

Comment: The domain for the solution are then three lines outside the circle.